# Changing A Value in table saving issue

Tags: php, mysql

This code should check if the row col intersection of LikedOne and the row where username is jim equals text "empty".

```
 $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT likedOne FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt1->bind_param('s',$username);
    //$username = $_POST["username"];
    $username ="jim";
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->store_result();

    $res = $stmt1->fetch();

    if ( $res == "empty"){
                echo "debug 3";
                $sql =  $conn->prepare("UPDATE UserData SET likedOne=? WHERE username=?");
                $sql->bind_param('ss',$TUsername,$Username);
        //      $TUsername = $_POST["TUsername"];
        //      $Username = $_POST["username"];
                $TUsername = "test";
                $Username = "jim";
                $sql->execute();


            }
```

The first time it does change it to test but then it still prints debug 3 meaning it it still registering the $res as "empty" even though it should be "test".

Edit that is not working!

```
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT likedOne FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt1->bind_param('s',$username);
    //$username = $_POST["username"];
    $username ="jim";
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->bind_result($res);
    $found_row = $stmt1->store_result();
 if ( $found_row && $res == "empty"){
        echo "debug 3";
        $sql =  $conn->prepare("UPDATE UserData SET likedOne=? WHERE username=?");
        $sql->bind_param('ss',$TUsername,$Username);
//      $TUsername = $_POST["TUsername"];
//      $Username = $_POST["username"];
        $TUsername = "test";
        $Username = "jim";
            $sql->execute();
}
```

Comment: You are declaring your variables after you bind them...

Comment: @Naruto And? Thats totally fine. No need to declare variables before you bind them.

Comment: So whats the issue with it thinking its "empty" still but its "test"

Comment: @Twinfriends I learned something new then :)

Comment: please help me with my question.

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt1->fetch()` doesn't return the contents of the `likedOne` column. It returns `TRUE` if a row was returned, `NULL` if there are no more rows in the result set, or `FALSE` if an error occurred.

To retrieve the data returned by a prepared statement, you need to use `$stmt1->bind_result()`.

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT likedOne FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param('s',$username);
//$username = $_POST["username"];
$username ="jim";
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->bind_result($res);
$found_row = $stmt1->store_result();

if ($found_row && $res == "empty") {
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure why your code that does this isn't working, but it's not necessary to do two queries, you can do it in one.

```
$sql =  $conn->prepare("UPDATE UserData SET likedOne=? WHERE username=? AND likedOne = 'empty'");
$sql->bind_param('ss',$TUsername,$Username);
//$TUsername = $_POST["TUsername"];
//$Username = $_POST["username"];
$TUsername = "test";
$Username = "jim";
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: When I var dump $res it says NULL

Comment: What about `$found_row`?

Comment: Are you sure `likedOne` really contains the string `empty`? What do you see if you do the query by hand?

Comment: OK i did pls review.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, but I posted another solution that avoids the `SELECT` query completely.